# Why are elephants not allowed in CWB?

Tags: rome-total-war

[This](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?513853-CWB-RULES) page on CWB rules for multiplayer in Rome Total War says that elephants are not permitted in multiplayer not because they are OP, but because they are easy to counter.

That doesn't sound right to me. Sure, if you try to rush the elephants up front, most probably they will be showered by flaming arrows and they will run amok but if you keep them out of the missile range until the last minute (which the infantry engages), then you will safely rush the elephants to the flanks of the enemy and sink their morale and make them rout and hence, win the battle.

So I think the real cause elephants are prevented is because they are overpowered. What do you think the real cause is?

Answer (score 1):

It says so in the link you posted

> (The lack of artillery and elephants is not because they provide an "unfair advantage", but precisely the opposite, **to discourage new players** from using **ineffective units** that are easily countered)

Emphasys mine.

It's not because they're strong nor weak, but because they are "*noobbait*", or in other words, things that appear strong, but are actually weak, which confuse and provide a bad game experience to inexperienced players.

Essentially, they are **misleading**, and without reading from any third party that elephants are a bad thing (likewise with the bottlenecks on the red line), and as such would provide bad gameplay for both sides

Comment: So how would you counter the scenario I presented in the question? Or is it not possible to counter this scenario and is that the reason that elephants are not allowed?

Comment: It may quite possibly be an effective strategy. However, it's still the same principle, a new player has no idea that Elephants work like that. Any other explanation would be theoryzing and as such off-topic

Comment: But in that sense, a new player could not have an idea to play effectively even by adhering to CWB too, right? For example, a new player might not know that you can't (shall not) use cav to make a frontal charge to spear units (or even non spear infantry).

Comment: That's just common sense, don't run into pointy things

Comment: The luck factor becomes too strong imho. They are neither OP nor UP but Rome wants to be a strategic game not a lottery game.

Comment: @utku How do I use elephants  effectively could probably be its own question.

Comment: Elephants aren't actually weak, if you know how to use them.